# Who was the first person to use Laplace transforms for circuit analysis?

Tags: laplace-transform

I am an electrical engineering student and I have been using Laplace transforms for circuit analysis. I would like to know: who was the first person to use Laplace transforms for the analysis of circuits? Is there any paper which was published which shows that Laplace transform is suitable for analysis of circuits?

Comment: https://www.britannica.com/science/Laplace-transform

Comment: Have you tried Google?

Comment: NB: 'Laplace transform' (use of "p") was not "really" 'Carson transform' (use of "s"). Originally "Transform Carson" = s * "Laplace transform". After "some" time ... it was definitely same definition -> "transform Laplace-Carson".

Comment: Other source ... https://resources.saylor.org/wwwresources/archived/site/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/ME401-1.2.2-LaplaceTransform.pdf

Comment: The Laplace transform was not a single invention but one idea out of group of similar ideas how to solve some equations in some different situation. The name Laplace transform was only given to the moder version of the method by Doetsch in his 1937 paper, so while similar methods have been used, there is a claim that Doetsch was the first to apply Laplace transform to engineering. So, we can't know who was the first to apply Laplace transform to solve anything with it, as the Laplace transform existed and was used before it was given the name Laplace transform.

Comment: I wonder if it was Oliver Heaviside?

Comment: Looks like Heaviside was using something functionally similar to Laplace transforms for transient analysis and then Thomas Bromwich made the connection between Heaviside's methods and Laplace methods. This is just based on a superficial reading of wikipedia.

Comment: Search perhaps in "annals of physics" original papers in some universities?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any paper which was published which shows that Laplace transform is suitable for analysis of circuits?

Well, there's no such thing like "a paper showing that LT is suitable for electrical circuit analysis".

If a system is modelled with differential equations then LT can be used to see the system's behaviour under some conditions. Doesn't matter if the system is electrical, physical, chemical, etc.

Comment: I kind of don't think this is true. There had to be someone who first made the connection. Whether anything in writing survives to this day, who knows, but someone had to make the connection in the nascent discipline of circuit analysis that Laplace methods were applicable. And there MIGHT be something in writing.

Comment: @mkeith I don't think there's someone who first made a connection between LT and EE, and therefore there shouldn't be any paper/article/book talking about whether using LT is suitable for electrical circuit analysis *(the main question is about this)*. Physicist have already been using LT in motion dynamics, linear systems and control theory even before electrical circuit analysis (19th century). Since they are the ones who first modelled and analysed electrical circuits, they must have started using directly LT or FT as they were quite familiar already from the topics I mentioned.

Comment: @RohatKılıç It's far more nuanced than is being discussed here. One must first distinguish between the "modern" and "earlier" forms of the Laplace transform and add to this the "operational calculi" term, as well. So you already have three distinct historical paths. For example, see: E. Koppelmann, *"The calculus of operations and the rise of abstract algebra,"* Arch. Hist. Ex. Sci. 8 (1972), 155-242, M.A.B. Deakin, *"The development of the Laplace transform,"* 1737-1937: I. Euler to Spitzer, 1737-1880. Arch. Hist. Ex. Sci. 25 (1981), 343-390, to start. There is much more.

Comment: @RohatKılıç But perhaps the final answer to all this is [M.A.B. Deakin's *"The Ascendancy of the Laplace Transform and how it Came About."*](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF00377050) I think any answer will need to deal with what's in that paper. For me, it's definitive.